# Calculation in your template with values passed in as context to display content

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Im having trouble displaying some divs using the context passed in through my view. In my views.py, i'm passing a value "total_used"" and "total".

views.py:

```py
def home(request):
    context = {
        "reward": [
            {
                "total": 5,
                "total_used": 2
            }
        ]
    }
    return render(request, "web/index.html", context)
```

Template:

```
  {% with ''|center:reward.total_used as range %}
  {% for _ in range %}
      <div class="red"></div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endwith %}

  <div class="blue"></div>

  <div id="reward-count">
      <h5>{{ reward.total_used }}/{{ reward.total }}</h5>
  </div>
```

So for example, I want 2 divs with class red, and 3 divs (reward.total- reward.total_used) with the class blue.

I have tried this but it didn't work:

```py
  {% with ''|center:reward.total_used as range %}
  {% for _ in range %}
      <div class="red"></div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endwith %}

    {% with ''|center:reward.total-reward.total_used as range %}
  {% for _ in range %}
      <div class="blue"></div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endwith %}

  <div id="reward-count">
      <h5>{{ reward.total_used }}/{{ reward.total }}</h5>
  </div>
```

Comment: what result do you get?

Comment: I get this error: Could not parse the remainder: '-reward.total_used' from '''|center:reward.total-reward.total_used'. The first instance of the template I showed above works fine. It displays 2 divs with class red. But I need to display 3 more div with class blue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the square brackets `[]` from `context` definition. Your `views.py` should look like this:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        "reward": {"total": 5, "total_used": 2}        
    }
    return render(request, "web/index.html", context)
```

Comment: Well, I need reward's value to be an array of objects, since there are going to be more than one. The main problem is doing the calculation total-total_used within the template.

Comment: array of dictionaries*

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calculating total-total_used in my views, then adding it to my context:

views.py:

```py
def home(request):
    context = {
        "rewards": [
            {
                "total": 5,
                "total_used": 2
            },
            {
                "total": 7,
                "total_used": 1        
            }
        ]
    }

    for  reward in context['rewards']:
        reward['total_not_used'] = reward['total'] - reward['total_used']

    return render(request, "web/index.html", context)
```

Template:

```
{% with ''|center:reward.total_used as range %}
{% for _ in range %}
<div class="reward reward-shaded"></div>
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}

{% with ''|center:reward.total_not_used as range %}
{% for _ in range %}
<div class="reward"></div>
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}

<div id="reward-count">
    <h5>{{ reward.total_used }}/{{ reward.total }}</h5>
</div>
```